# How to configure asp.net core to return react front end and work with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, react-router

I would like my backend to serve up my front end (which is written in react). I added the following cade to `program.cs`:

```
var frontEndBuildDirectory = "Path to front end build directory";
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(frontEndBuildDirectory ),
    RequestPath = ""
});
```

My understanding is that this code does two things:

1. If a request's url starts with the host name of my backend (`localhost:xyzw`), everything following the host name will be a virtual path into `frontEndBuildDirectory`.
2. When a request is made into `frontEndBuildDirectory` (the directory itself, not a file within the directory), then the response is the `index.html` file within `frontEndBuildDirectory`.

The problem is that my react code uses the react-router library. If I make a request to the backend (`localhost:xyzw`), the front end is served. Then when I click on something that changes the route (using react router), the url changes to `localhost:xyzw/route1` and the everything works. However, if I try to search up `localhost:xyzw/route1`, I get a page not found error.

My understanding is that this happens because there is no file named `route1` in `frontEndBuildDirectory`.

What is the proper way to make requests like `localhost:xyzw/route1` not give a page not found error?

Comment: The general gist when serving up React apps is to redirect all page requests for sub-routes to the root index.html file so your React app loads and handles the routing internally. Take a look as the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to see plenty of examples for different server environments and if there is anything specific to your server environment.

Comment: Thank you. If you arrange your comment as an answer I will credit you.

Comment: Haha, I'm not a .net developer and I have no idea any specifics you needed to do. I was only trying to provide the best hint I possibly know and get you headed in the right direction. You are more than welcome to answer your own question for what worked for you.